# How to obtain the density matrix using tomography in the real device?

Tags: qiskit, programming, ibm-q-experience, quantum-fourier-transform, state-tomography

I am trying to run the QFT algorithm for n=5 (n number of qubits). The number of experiments that it generates is bigger than the one allowed by the IBM devices (i.e. 75). Therefore, I have tried to used the IBMQJobManager but this is not working as my result is not the counts but the density matrix obtain from the tomography process. Is it possible to make it work? I have made the following attempt (qft is a function that I have created that implements the QFT algorithm):

```
n=5
beta=0.5*np.pi
state=initial_state_QFT(n,beta)
qr=QuantumRegister(n)
cr=ClassicalRegister(n)
qc=QuantumCircuit(qr)

qc.initialize(state,qr)
qft(qc,n)
qst = tomo.state_tomography_circuits(qc, qr)
job = job_manager.run(qst, backend=device, name='foo',shots=8192)
statefit = tomo.StateTomographyFitter(job.results(), qst)
p, M, weights = statefit._fitter_data(True, 0.5)
M_dg = np.conj(M).T
linear_inversion_matrix = np.linalg.inv(M_dg @ M) @ M_dg
rho = linear_inversion_matrix @ p
rho = np.reshape(rho, (2**n, 2**n))
```

Thank you in advance for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

`IBMQJobManager.run()` returns a `ManagedResult`, but `StateTomographyFitter` expects a `Result` object. Unfortunately there is no easy way to convert the former into the latter, so you'll have to combine the results yourself:

```
job_set = job_manager.run(qst, backend=device, name='foo',shots=8192)
jobs = job_set.jobs()
new_result = copy.deepcopy(jobs[0].result())
for idx in range(1, len(jobs)):
    new_result.results.extend(jobs[idx].result().results)
statefit = tomo.StateTomographyFitter(new_result, qst)
```

This is an interesting use case. Looks like Job Manager should really support returning a `Result` object.

Comment: Thank you for your help, my only question is in the last line, where you have written job.results() it should be something else as no variable called job is defined.

Comment: Oops copy & paste error. Updated to use the `new_result` that has combined results from all jobs.

Comment: Thank you again. I still have a problem because when I run the code I get the following error: The Qobj uses gates (['h', 'sdg']) that are not among the basis gates (['u1', 'u2', 'u3', 'cx', 'id']) [1106]. I have unrolled the quantum circuit object in these basis gates and I have checked that it has been done propertly. Anyway it does not work.

Comment: Unlike `execute`, `IBMQJobManager.run()` doesn't transpile the circuits for you (e.g. no gate unrolling), so you'll have to do that yourself. Can you check that **all** circuits in `qst` have been unrolled to the basis gates?

Comment: I changed this:                                                                                                           
    pass_ = Unroller(['u1', 'u2', 'u3', 'cx', 'id'])
    pm = PassManager([pass_])
    circ = pm.run(qc)
    qst = tomo.state_tomography_circuits(circ, qr)

Comment: But it did not work, thank you so much anyway!!

Comment: `state_tomography_circuits` injects non-basis gates, so you'll need to unroll the circuits returned by `state_tomography_circuits` (i.e. `qst` in your example).